# How to read a file by line with threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

I've been trying to optimize reading very large files using node and started hitting bottlenecks so thought I'd give threads in node a go.

I'm trying to read 2 files

the needles which contain 1000 - 100,000s uuids I'm trying to find I'm reading the sync and splitting the file.

the amount of lines isn't known before hand.

the haystack which contains hundreds of millions of lines of uuids 3.4gb+ in size i'm wanting to split it by the amount of reads and split up the reading of the file.

```
// example needle.txt/haystack.txt
a57a258d-7e56-40e1-962e-d683a17d7d3b
4380b26b-36d3-4cfe-ae3b-9121bf1f0c12
ebda3a08-857f-41d2-99bf-a288f0470af8
```

process.argv[3] is needles and process.argv[4] is the haystack i can also accept the haystack from `process.stdin`

what i'm struggling with is how to handle splitting the file whilst retaining the lines of the file is this possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');

const cluster = require('cluster');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const fileSize = fs.statSync(process.argv[4]).size;

    const threads = 4;

    const n = new Set(
        fs
            .readFileSync(process.argv[3])
            .toString()
            .split('\n')
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        const buffer = {};
        const worker = cluster.fork();

        worker.on('message', function(lines) {
          // main thread received buffer from thread
          /*
             how to combine the data so i can read the lines

             if (n.has(line)) {
               console.log(line)   
             }
          */
        });

        worker.on('exit', threadNum => {
          // exited thread all parts read from that thread
        })

        worker.send({start: i * (fileSize / threads), end: (i + 1) * (fileSize / threads), i});
    }
} else {
    process.on('message', function({ start, end, i }) {
        /*
           worker code here we start streaming from one part of the file 
           to another
        */
        createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[4], {
                start,
                end
            })
        })
        .on('line', data => {
          // sending data back to main thread with thread number
          process.send({data, thread: i});
        })
        .on('close', () => process.exit(i))
    });
}
```

is it possible to tell readline.createInterface to continue reading until it hits a char? can I combine the buffers by passing the thread number and splitting in the main thread?

any help would be much appreciated.

if anyone wants to know the im running cmd

`node index.js --needles needles.txt haystack.txt`

Comment: have you looked at creating a readStream for the file then processing the data chunks?

Comment: yeah yeah i've done that I'm trying to see if I can optimize it with doing it with threads as the speeds i was getting weren't that great

Comment: Answer below, check it out

Answer (score 0):

I commented the code for a better explanation of what's going on..  The main idea is to pass any data you are working with to the worker since the worker can't see anything initialized in the master.  I would probably place the master section and worker section into their own files to keep things neat.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log("Master started.");
    // Only need filesystem access in the master node and readline in the master node
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rl = require('readline');

    // Number of cpus is the number of threads, we'll read 1000 lines before
    // sending the work to a worker to process and well set up a roundRobin style
    // counter to send data to each thread as equally as we can
    const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    const numOfLines = 1000;
    let lineNum = 0;
    let lines = [];
    let roundRobin = 0;

    // Hold all our workers and teh number of calls to the worker
    let workers = [];
    let usage = {};

    // Handle your messages this is the worker handler
    function messageHandler(message) {
        // increment the number of calls to the specific worker
        if (usage.hasOwnProperty(message.worker)) {
            usage[message.worker]++;
        } else {
            usage[message.worker] = 1;
        }

        // set the next worker
        roundRobin = (roundRobin+1)%(numCPUs);

        // if the text was found in the line return the line numbers
        if (message.found) {
            console.log("Line Numbers:", message.lineNo);
        }

    }

    // Start workers
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        workers.push(cluster.fork());
    }

    // When worker sends back a message handle it
    for (const id in workers) {
        workers[id].on('message', messageHandler);
    }

    // Start reading lines from the file stream
    const readLine = rl.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[4]),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    // When a line is recieved from realLine push it to an array and update the count
    // when the number of lines reaches a defined chunk of data to process pause the
    // readline send the chunk with it's line number and the search term then resume
    // the roundRobin handles the worker assignments
    readLine.on('line', (line) => {
        //console.log('Line:', line);
        ++lineNum;
        lines.push(line);
        if (lineNum%numOfLines === 0) {
            readLine.pause();
            workers[roundRobin].send({
                start: lineNum, 
                lines: lines.slice(0), 
                search: process.argv[3]
            });
            lines = [];
            readLine.resume();
        }
    });

    // When the end of the file is reached thsi is where you can exit the program if you want
    readLine.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Done processing the file');
    });

} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    console.log("Worker Started:", cluster.worker.id);

    // When the worker recieves a message process the message
    process.on('message', (message)=>{
        let start = Number(message.start);
        let lines = message.lines;
        let search = message.search.trim();

        // Initialize a swicth to determine if we found the data or not which
        // line numbers we found the text on
        let found = false;
        let lineNo = [];

        // Iterate over the lines passed in and search for the search term in the line
        // if it's found add the line number to the array and set found to true
        // the start variable hold the start of this chunks line number
        lines.forEach(function(val, ind) {
            let text = val.toLowerCase();
            if (text.search(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                lineNo.push(start + ind);
                found = true;
            }
        });

        // Send back the data to master
        process.send({found: found, lineNo: lineNo, search: search, start: start, worker: cluster.worker.id});
    });
}
```

Comment: hey :) interesting approach one thing too note is that  process.argv[3] is a file path not the string you're searching for and the number of lines is not known before hand

Comment: I see so process.argv[3] is a list of uuids that are being searched for in process.argv[4].  Yikes that's going to take a while.

Comment: yeah i've got a working version at the moment where i pass off the lines from the haystack to the workers but thats taking slower than just streaming

Answer (score 0):

Try this below, basically load the needles file and then send all the search terms will the haystack.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log("Master started.");
    // Only need filesystem access in the master node and readline in the master node
    const fs = require('fs');
    const rl = require('readline');

    // Number of cpus is the number of threads, we'll read 1000 lines before
    // sending the work to a worker to process and well set up a roundRobin style
    // counter to send data to each thread as equally as we can
    const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    const numOfLines = 1000;
    let lineNum = 0;
    let lines = [];
    let roundRobin = 1;
    let foundItems = {};

    let needles = [];

    // Hold all our workers and teh number of calls to the worker
    let workers = [];

    // Handle your messages this is the worker handler
    function messageHandler(message) {
        // set the roundRobin only when the thread is complete
        roundRobin = (roundRobin+1)%(numCPUs);

        // a found message
        for (let items in message.found) {
            // add the array of lineno to the collective found items
            foundItems[items] = foundItems[items].concat(message.found[items]);
        }
    };

    // Log to console all the found items at the end
    function logFoundItems(){
        console.log(foundItems);
    };

    // Start workers
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        workers.push(cluster.fork());
    }

    // When worker sends back a message handle it
    for (const id in workers) {
        workers[id].on('message', messageHandler);
    }

    // First file of uuids to search for
    const searchFile = rl.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    let readLine = null; 

    // Load the search lines into an array and set up the collective search item arrays
    searchFile.on('line', (ln)=>{
        let item = ln.trim();
        needles.push(item);
        foundItems[item.toLowerCase()] = [];
    });

    // Whole search file is loaded start streaming the haystack file
    searchFile.on('close', ()=>{
        console.log('Search File Loaded... Starting processing.');
        // Start reading lines from the file stream
        readLine = rl.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(process.argv[4]),
            crlfDelay: Infinity
        });

        // When a line is recieved from realLine push it to an array and update the count
        // when the number of lines reaches a defined chunk of data to process pause the
        // readline send the chunk with it's line number and the search term then resume
        // the roundRobin handles the worker assignments
        readLine.on('line', (line) => {
            ++lineNum;
            lines.push(line);
            if (lineNum%numOfLines === 0) {
                readLine.pause();
                workers[roundRobin].send({
                    start: lineNum, 
                    lines: lines.slice(0), 
                    search: needles
                });
                lines = [];
                readLine.resume();
            }
        });

        // When the end of the file is reached this is where you can exit the program if you want
        readLine.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Done processing the file');
            setTimeout(()=>{
                logFoundItems();
                process.exit(0);
            }, 1000);

        });

    });

} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    console.log("Worker", cluster.worker.id, "Started.");

    // When the worker recieves a message process the message
    process.on('message', (message)=>{
        let start = Number(message.start);
        let lines = message.lines;
        let search = message.search;
        let foundItems = {};

        // Iterate over the search terms and check the lines send back a 
        // message for each term found and which line
        search.forEach((uuid)=>{
            lines.forEach((line, ind)=>{
                let lineText = line.toLowerCase();
                let searchTerm = uuid.toLowerCase();
                if (lineText.search(searchTerm) > -1) {
                    if (!foundItems.hasOwnProperty(searchTerm)) {
                        foundItems[searchTerm] = [];
                    }
                    foundItems[searchTerm].push(start+ind);
                }
            });
        });

        // Send the message back to the master node
        process.send({
            type: 'found', 
            found: foundItems, 
            workerID: cluster.worker.id
        });

    });
}
```